# I can not install npm package in commandline eg vs code terminal or visual studio package manager

Tags: node.js, debugging, npm, visual-studio-code, npm-install

when I trying to install package from npm in vscode, receive following message and package do not install.

npm install -g express

**changed 50 packages, and audited 51 packages in 7s
**2 packages are looking for funding
run `npm fund` for details
found 0 vulnerabilities
Waiting for the debugger to disconnect...****

Answer (score 0):

the `-g` flag [installs the package globally](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-install#global), which I don't think you are wanting. If you have the project setup (by running `npm init` in the root folder of the project), drop the `-g` flag and just install express with:

```
npm install express
```

Then, if you want, to clean up having express installed globally you can use:

```
npm uninstall -g express
```